# Round Robin Tournament - Question Strategy

Tags: combinatorics

> In a round robin tournament, every player plays against every other player exactly once. A win gives a player a point, and a loss gives the loser no points. Find the last three digits of the greatest possible score difference between the first and second highest scorers, if there are 2010 members in the tournament.

$\textbf{Where I'm Stuck:}$

I really have no clue on where to start with this problem, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

$\textbf{General Concerns:}$
In general, I have come across of several problems of this style, involving a round robin tournament. These questions generally have some form a unique restriction on the tournament (i.e. wins are only in cycles, or a certain group of members in the round robin tournament has a certain ratio of wins to the other member groups). The questions then proceed to ask for the number of a certain type of member, total number of members, or the quantity of a specific match outcome (i.e. a certain type of win between two specific player types). What would be a general way to attack these problems? I notice that usually the first step in solutions is to express the number of wins and losses as both equal to $n \choose 2$, where $n$ equals the number of members in the tournament.

Answer (score 1):

The *particular* problem you have posed is easily solved.

The highest scorer must win all $2009$ matches against opponents.

And in order to create the greatest difference, all the other $2009$ players who will play $2008$ matches each among themselves must win/lose equal number of matches  thus $1004$ wins

Thus greatest possible difference in scores @ $1$ point/win $= 2009-1004 =1005$

We didn't even have to use $\binom{n}{k}$ for this simple problem

And, oh, the last three digits of the difference are $005$ !

When you stipulate other conditions, those conditions need to be clearly specified to get an answer.

Comment: It technically remains to show that it is possible to have each of the $k:=2008$ players finish with at most $1004$ wins. If $k$ were odd, you can have everyone win $(k-1)/2$ times with a simple cyclic assignment: number the players $0,\dots, k-1$ and let player $i$ win against players $i+1,\dots, i+(k-1)/2 \mod k$. However $k$ is even here so you'd need to be a bit more careful.

Comment: Would $005$ be the correct answer then or no? How would you solve it then if you can't assume that all the remaining players have $1004$ wins?

Comment: @BenjaminWang: Leaving out the person winning all matches, the number of players is not even, there are 2009 players who each play 2008 matches among themselves

Comment: Ah yes I forgot the losses against the first player. Among the $2008$ remaining players (so ignoring losses against the player who wins everything), they would each win $1004$ and lose $1003$. This is easily done by a cyclic scheme. Your answer is correct but this detail would be nice.